How do you return multiple items from a dropdown list in one cell? Google Sheets?
I have created a large dropdown list in a google sheets cell.  I would like to choose multiple items from this list to show in one cell.  Is there  a formula that will allow me to accomplish this?
I was able to create the dropdown from a list, but it will only return one item in the cell.  I need to be able to choose multiple docs from the list.
